# Branch Points of $f(z)=\log\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{2}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

I am doing a problem concerning the branch points of the complex function $$f(z)=\log\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{2}\right)$$

The question begins by asking what the branch points of $f(z)$ are, and then tells you what they are; it says that $z=0,\pm i, \infty$ are the branch points.  The latter three ($-i,i,\infty$) all make perfect sense, but the $z=0$ does not.  Nor does Wolfram Alpha seem to think so [either](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=branch%20points%20of%20log%28%281%2bsqrt%281%2bz%5E2%29%29/2%29).

The problem continues by saying the following:

> If we define $\sqrt{1+z^2}|_{z=0}=1$, show that the origin is not a branch point of this function.  Draw a set of branch cuts to make the function single valued.

This makes it seem like it's saying that $z=0$ is a branch point of $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ by saying that $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ is multi-valued for positive real numbers.  While $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ is certainly multi-valued, the branch points seem to simply be $i$ and $-i$, since these are the zeroes of $\sqrt{1+z^2}$, and I don't see how $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ is multi-valued at $z=0$ (though theoretically $-1$ is another root of 1).

I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint as to why 0 is a branch point of this function and why the definition of $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ at $z=0$ is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We must dispense the assumption that the square root of a positive integer is uniquely defined; indeed, $(-1)^2=1^2=1$, so that both $-1$ and 1 are valid roots of $1$.

Theoretically, this is an issue for every positive integer, but the reason that $\sqrt{1}=-1$ is important is that it offers the opportunity for $\frac{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{2}$ to be zero, at which point $\log \frac{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{2}$ will be undefined, and will become a branch point of $\log$.  By *defining* $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ at $z=0$ to be $1$, we eliminate the possibility of there being a zero of $\frac{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{2}$, and thus $\infty,\pm i$ are the only remaining branch points.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretion for the brunch cut and points of the function $f(z)=log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{2}\right)$.

1. Since by definition, $\sqrt{1+z^2}=e^{\frac12Log(1+z^2)}$ where $Log(z)$ is principal natural logarithm, $1+z^2\in(-\infty,0]$ gives the brunch-cut $(-\infty,-1]i\cup[1,\infty)i$. Therefore, $\{-i,i,\infty\}$ are branch points.
2. For $f(z)$, assuming that the brunch-cut of $\log z$ is $(-\infty,0]e^{i\alpha}$, we also need to mark those $z$ with $\frac{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{2}=-te^{i\alpha}$ where $t\in[0,\infty)$. This implies that $z=2\sqrt{t}e^{i\alpha/2}\sqrt{1+te^{i\alpha}}$. Hence, at $t=0$, $z=0$ is brunch-point.